# predict VAR with missing values

Tags: r, missing-data, forecasting

I have a data set like this

```
data <- ts(matrix(rnorm(144, mean=0, sd=1), ncol=6), start=c(2007,1), frequency=12)
```

I computed two factors.

```
factors <- ts(t(t(eigen(cor(data))$vectors[,1:2] %*% 
             sqrt(diag(eigen(cor(data))$values[1:2]))) %*% 
             t(scale(data))), start=c(2007,1), frequency=12)
colnames(factors) <- c("f1", "f2")
```

I combined the factors with the data set.

```
favar <- ts.union(factors, data)
colnames(favar) <- c(colnames(factors), colnames(data))
```

Then, I wanted to estimate a VAR.

```
require(vars)
model <- VAR(favar, type="const", ic="FPE")
```

Unfortunately, some of the coefficients are NA. When I predict my model, it will only produce missing values.

```
predict(model, n.ahead=4, ci=0.95)
$f1
 fcst lower upper     CI
[1,]   NA    NA    NA 3.6669
[2,]   NA    NA    NA     NA
[3,]   NA    NA    NA     NA
[4,]   NA    NA    NA     NA
```

How can I handle the missing values in my model, so that I can forecast it? I've already tried forecast() of the `forecast` package with the same results. Unfortunately, I couldn't find something helpful in the Package ‘vars’ guide and helping page of VAR() either.

Comment: You are estimating `8x9=72` coefficients with only `24` sample points. Your system is unidentifiable as you see from `summary(model)`.

Comment: @Khashaa: Apparently, the unidentifiable system is not my only problem. I have redone it with `192` sample points (`rnorm(1152)`) and VAR() still produces missing values in some coefficients, even though I estimate the VAR with only one lag.